# setPreferredWidth() for table column display incorrectly

Tags: java, jtable

I have a table like this image, That doesn't contain any data

[image]

So i want remove spaces after Send column, And i'am using

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(5);   //first column size
System.out.println(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getPreferredWidth());
```

But it prints `15` !!
if i set the `setPreferredWidth` to a number that be greater than `15` it affects the column
but if i set the `setPreferredWidth` to a number that be smaller than `15` it doesn't affect the column, and it takes `15` by default

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setMaxWidth(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setMaxWidth(int)) to define not only prefered size but also max one, in your case

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(5);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(5);
System.out.println(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).getPreferredWidth());
```

OUTPUT:

```
5
```

Comment: Thanks its solved ,But we must use both not just `setPreferredWidth` or `setMaxWidth` !!